# Am i using the correct version of visual studio for app development?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**My current Xamrin  app deveenvironment on vs2017** :

a)Xamarin.Android  version v7
[android references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31bCO.png)

b)Xamarin.Forms version 3.4
 [forms references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWVvZ.png)

c)Xamrin SDK platoform 28,27 are  [sdk manager Tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efRzU.png)

**Reason for confusion** :

a) When i googled for the documentation related Xamarin.Andorid references

@https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/package-summary it showed a message that it is deprecated

b)Also my Xamarin.Forms references are not the latest as per the release info @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/

c)But  my android sdk are  new to latest available in vs2017

***Main question :***

How is the Xamarin.version and xamarin.Forms affect my app development ?Should i upgrade to the latest versions of the same  ( for that i need to install vs2019)?

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to this question.  Generally speaking you will want to use the latest versions of everything in order to have the latest bug fixes and support for the newest APIs.  Xamarin is no longer supported on VS2017 so you should upgrade to VS 2019.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use the latest version of them, I will suggest that do that with no doubt.

You also could refer to [Xamarin.Forms release notes and roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/) to know their difference betwenn their vesions.

About the version of Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2019 will support all the features of Xamarin now, however Visual Studio 2017 will not. Also can refer to [the realease notes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements).